# Hack syntax: What does question mark followed by object operator mean?

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

In Hack, what is happening here and what does it mean? How do you read it?

```
 $foobar = $foo?->bar();
```

Comment: That actually isn't valid syntax

Comment: @JohnConde, do you recognize this as Hack (hacklang.org)? I'm new to both, so I might be mistaken about the language. But I'm not mistaken about the syntax.

Comment: @JohnConde this is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @bigT since this has been incorrectly closed as a duplicate, I can't submit this as an answer.

The operator is the [null safe](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/operators/null-safe) operator. If `$foo` is `null`, then `null` is returned. Otherwise, it acts as the normal object access operator.

Comment: @simon_w This was *correctly* marked as a dupe when it was closed because the OP marked this as a PHP question. All PHP questions relation to symbols are dupes of the question above. Since the question has been clarified this can be reopened.

Comment: @JohnConde, thanks. Could you unmark it as dupe?

Comment: @simon_w, you are right, this is Hack indeed. Are you able to submit answer now? Please do, and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I voted to reopen but we still need two votes for it to reopen. I don't know why I couldn't do so automatically. I guess they changed something that prevents that now.

Comment: Strange.. It says on your PHP badge "Users with the PHP badge can single-handedly close PHP questions as duplicates and reopen them as needed."